# Django - After installing "Bootstrap4" with pip, got syntax error on settings.py

Tags: python, syntax-error, django-bootstrap4

After installing "Bootstrap4" using pip, add tags in html files, and adding it in requirements.txt and settings.py, do migrate but it shows this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Mehrab\menv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Mehrab\menv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\Mehrab\menv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\Mehrab\menv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\Mehrab\menv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 916, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\~\socialize\settings.py", line 72
    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'socialize.wsgi.application'
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I didn't find any problem in settings.py

Comment: Can you please check what's around the line `WSGI_APPLICATION = 'socialize.wsgi.application''`

Comment: @MHHabib I checked every bracket, comma, parenthesis. all are correct, but still this error

Comment: Did you added `"bootstrap4"` in `INSTALLED_APPS` also did you load `Bootstrap` in your template like `{% load bootstrap4 %}`?

Comment: @MHHabib yes, even added in "requirements.txt" file in project